# Multiplying columns with missing values in Python (pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with multiple columns which i need to multiply. One of these columns have missing values in them, what I would like is that when I am multiplying the columns, the missing values are skipped, and the columns which do have values in them are used for the result.

For example,

```
A B C

1 2 1

2 3 NaN

1 4 NaN

1 1 2
```

For each row, i would like the result to be column D with following values:-

```
2

6

4

2
```

I have tried .fillna(), .notnull(), .isnull() and .dropna() but I did not get the desired result.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I had tried:

> df['D'] = df['A'].fillna()*df['B']*df['C']
>
> df

Comment: Can you edit your post to show us how you used ```.fillna()```? It looks to me like that will be involved with the solution, but you might just have missed something in actually implementing it.

Comment: You line 1 in your expected out it is 2, but the  value in your input dataframe is 1.  should this value be overwritten?

Comment: Hey, I have edited the question and .fillna() is not working for me, I am still getting NaN in the output column @LTheriault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of utilizing `.fillna()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({"a":[3,6,7],"b":[2,5,7],"c":[5,np.nan,np.nan]})
```

A quick look at `data`:

```
a   b   c
3   2   5.0
6   5   NaN
7   7   NaN
```

Then utilize `.fillna()`:

```
data.fillna(1).prod(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
30.0
30.0
49.0
```

I noticed that you used `.fillna()`. If you could include attempted code, it would help us debug your code for a more precise solution.

Comment: Hey, I edited the question and tried your way but it is not working for me. I am still getting NaN. Do I need to import Numpy to use .fillna() ?

Comment: Your code didn't try what is shown here. First, fillna() needs to be applied to all of the columns. You aren't applying it to column C, so column C still has nulls. Second, you need to specify that you are filling null values with 1 like this answer. The code you show has no argument passed into fillna.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['C'].fillna(df['A'].mul(df['B']))
```